# Will this change in Text.js impact anything and is it necessary?

Tags: react-native

I have made the following change in Text.js, I updated the line
  from
  this 
 **this.props.onPress && this.props.onPress(e)**
  to
 **this.props.onPress && this.props.onPress(e,this.props)**

so that I can access attributes 
eg:  , '<' Text customAttribute=xxx '>' '<'/Text'>'   -->

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: you changed it in the react-native source code directly ??

Comment: Editor is processing the HTML tags. I dont know how to avoid it. This is my first question on stackoverflow

Comment: Yes, I did change the code

Comment: I suppose the react native way to do this is to write a custom component , pass the the customAttribute as prop and have a callback method on parent component. But in my case iam using 'react-native-simple-table' and cell in the table will only accept Text component as its child